# how to bind to billing service in application with multiple purchase activities

Tags: android, binding, android-activity, android-service, in-app-billing

I am writing application where in my MainActivity I have list of items. When item is clicked new DetailsActivity is started showing details of this item and Button to purchase it. This app is based on Dungeons example from Google.

**I wonder how should I manage the connection to BillingService?**

**Option 1)** Should I create the BillingService in MainActivity as in Dungeons example and then bind to that service from every ProjectDetailsActivity when requesting purchase? Im not sure if binding to BillingService which is binding to IMarketBillingService won't get too messy...

I tried to do this, but I'm not sure how to bind to BillingService from Activity other than MainActivity. I did it how you usually bind to service:

```
//ProjectDetailsActivity.java
private ServiceConnection billingConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mBillingService = ((BillingService.MyBinder)service).getService();
        if(mBillingService!=null)
            Log.d(tag, "Bound to BillingService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBillingService = null;
    }
};

public void unbind() {
    try {
        unbindService(billingConnection);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // This might happen if the service was disconnected
    }
}

onCreate(){...}

onStart(){...
billingIntent = new Intent(ProjectDetailsActivity.this, BillingService.class);
bindService(billingIntent, billingConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
...}
```

**Option 2)** Should I pass somehow the BillingService from MainActivity to ProjectDetailsActivities? I yes, how? With Parcelable or something? I didn't see possibility to do this and I assumed it is not the right way.

**Option 3)** Should I create the BillingService in every ProjectDetailsActivity? As above I don't think it's ok, as all those services bil be redundant after purchase.

**Other options..?**

I would like to hear how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither option. Don't think about "creating" or "passing" a Service. You can communicate with a Service from any activity with intents.

I wrote an open-source [library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) for Android In-app Billing that handles this for you. The source code might also help to clarify some concepts about Services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could explain me why binding to BillingService is a bad idea? I thought it's quite clever solution. Can I run methods from service with intents?

Comment: Yes, you can. IIRC, the BillingService in Dungeons is not a bound service. Bound services are not a bad idea; they're just another Android tool.